# Android - gRPC client - From Java to Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, protocol-buffers, grpc

I am coming today because I can't find the way to use gRPC and protobuf with my Kotlin app in order to exchange with my API.

In fact, I have a Go API and a Android (java) client. My exchange works, everything is fine, but now I would like to try with Kotlin. However, I can't find the way to generate my gRPC client stub...

I followed the different tutorials/blogs:

- https://grpc.io/blog/kotlin-gradle-projects
- https://medium.com/@umesh8346/grpc-in-kotlin-android-d67daa978450
- https://medium.com/@elye.project/android-protobuf-in-kotlin-a1c33014a4e2

However, at the end, nothing is working... Either I have errors or I need updates, or even it generates the file, but then I get error once the file is generated...

With the second link (which is the one that worked more far than the others), I have this error:

[image]

My protobuf file is the following (I just took the easiest one)

```
// Copyright 2015 gRPC authors.
//
// Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
// you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
// You may obtain a copy of the License at
//
//     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
//
// Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
// distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
// WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
// See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
// limitations under the License.

syntax = "proto3";

package helloworld;

// The greeting service definition.
service Greeter {
  // Sends a greeting
  rpc SayHello (HelloRequest) returns (HelloReply) {}
}

// The request message containing the user's name.
message HelloRequest {
  string name = 1;
}

// The response message containing the greetings
message HelloReply {
  string message = 1;
}
```

I followed as well two others links plus one github repo with no success so I hope anyone that has already achieved it can help me :)

Thanks for your help !

## Edit 1 - Based on comments exchanged

> Module

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "eyesapp.co.eyes"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'

    implementation 'io.grpc:grpc-protobuf:1.13.2'
    implementation 'io.grpc:grpc-stub:1.13.2'
}

buildscript {
    ext {
        protobufPluginVersion = '0.8.5'
        grpcVersion = '1.12.0'
        protocVersion = '3.2.0'
    }

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.google.protobuf:protobuf-gradle-plugin:$protobufPluginVersion"
    }

}

apply plugin: 'com.google.protobuf'
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {

    implementation "io.grpc:grpc-netty:$grpcVersion"
    implementation "io.grpc:grpc-protobuf:$grpcVersion"
    implementation "io.grpc:grpc-stub:$grpcVersion"
}

protobuf {

    generatedFilesBaseDir = "$projectDir/src"

    protoc {
        artifact = "com.google.protobuf:protoc:$protocVersion"
    }

    plugins {
        grpc {
            artifact = "io.grpc:protoc-gen-grpc-java:$grpcVersion"
        }
    }
    generateProtoTasks {
        all()*.plugins {
            grpc {
                outputSubDir = 'java'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

> Project

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.11'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.3'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: AFAIK, javax doesn't exist on Android.

Comment: What do you mean by javax?

Comment: Nvm. I mean the package, which is used in the first annotation. Missed the part where it was generated ^^"

Comment: Oh ok got it now haha so do you think is there any Android Kotlin implementation for gRPC?

Comment: I see `error: package helloworld.Helloworld does not exist` in the errors, and also `GreeterGrpc.java` being under `src/` instead of the default `build/generated/source/proto`. Your `build.gradle` may be misconfigured. Can you post them?

Comment: Edited based on your comments :)

Comment: Try adding `compileOnly "javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:1.2"` to your dependencies.  This should resolve the `Generated` class. Can you list the files under `app/src/debug/java/helloworld`?